# System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, asp.net-web-api

I made an installer with Microsoft installer project, the project runs an exe which downloads a zip file, extracts it and then runs an exe from the extracted folder.

The exe from the extracted folder makes a request from the web api. The web api is on local host. 
The exe throws an exception on this line

```
response = client.GetAsync(URL).result();
```

but if I run the exe manually from the extracted folder, it runs just fine without throwing any exceptions.

I have tried this

```
ServicePointManager
    .ServerCertificateValidationCallback += 
    (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

and this,

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

None of these worked for me.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(URL);
try { response = client.GetAsync(/api/user/1).Result; }
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.writeline(e);
}
```

Comment: `+=` to the `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` may still maintain the default method, try with `=` instead.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but it doesn't work.